# Is my browsing history on the server hidden when I use a VPN?

Tags: vpn, server, logging

I am a client within a server in a school.
My computer has a static IP address to enable me to connect to the internet.

We have a server that records the browsing history of the computers that are connected.

If I use a VPN, will this prevent capturing my browsing history in those logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume it's your own computer, because you likely wouldn't care about your IP being static otherwise.

If you use a VPN, your network activity is encrypted from you all the way to the VPN service.  They're not going to see it, but they'll likely know you're using a VPN if that matters.  This is one of the primary functions of using a VPN.

Just make sure to check https://www.whatismyip.com/ before browsing to make sure your VPN is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on where the logging-server gets its information from.
If it gets its information from the packets that come through the gateway a VPN will hide your browsing history.

But if the history is pulled directly from the computer you browse from a VPN is not a solution to stop the logging.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the IT guys are smart and have direct monitoring of your PC, including all of the initial requests, most likely not. I would assume this is the case at most schools.
At least my brother's school has such monitoring. A VPN wasn't particularly useful, as it already had direct access to the network activities.

On top of that, It doesn't allow anything installed. So even if you can get a VPN on there, there might be a chance that it will not work out.

Comment: Thanks for the grammatical edits and change of structure! Appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick addendum to answer from @Nick Simonian.

If your school required you to install any CA certs like they did at mine then using a VPN might not do you any good.

Basically it allows the school to perform deep packet inspection through a sort of MITM attack by making any secured sites use their cert instead. Not sure if VPNs are immune to this.

Comment: The school would use the certificate to decrypt https traffic. VPN traffic should use the certificate profided by the server. This means the school won't be able to decrypt the packets.

Comment: Ah, good to know.